# Lemma 2.4.1 Introductory Functional Analysis - Kreyszig :Confirmation of my understanding

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I see that questions relating to this lemma have been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043581/lemma-2-4-1-in-erwin-kreyszigs-introductory-functional-analysis-with-applicati/1239096)  and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238998/i-need-help-understanding-the-proof-of-lemma-2-4-1-from-kreyszigs-functional-an)  .
But my question is quite different in the sense , that i believe that i have understood what the author intends to say but i need a confirmation if my understanding is correct . 
The lemma is : [image]
[image]

So this is my understanding : 
To prove the lemma , we would prove that 
$$\exists c> 0 ,\text{ for which} \forall \alpha_{i} \in R ,  \text{ we have }||\alpha_{1}x_{1} +\alpha_{2}x_{2} +\alpha_{3}x_{3} +.....+ \alpha_{n}x_{n}|| \geq c(|\alpha_{1}|+|\alpha_{2}|+|\alpha_{3|}+.....+|\alpha_{n}|) \tag{1} $$ 
where the set of vectors $$\{x_{1},x_{2},.....,x_{n}\}$$ are independent and $x_{i} \in X$ where $X$ is a normed space with some norm.

Now the first idea that comes to me is that because the set of vectors are independent .We know , from linear algebra , that $$\alpha_{1}x_{1} +\alpha_{2}x_{2} +\alpha_{3}x_{3} +.....+ \alpha_{n}x_{n}  = 0 $$  only when all $\alpha_{i}$ are zero , in which case the inequality of the lemma will hold true for all $c$ . But let $\alpha_{i} \neq 0$ . In this case the quantity  $$\alpha_{1}x_{1} +\alpha_{2}x_{2} +\alpha_{3}x_{3} +.....+ \alpha_{n}x_{n} \tag{1}$$   will have some value but we don't know what it is but the  norm over it would be some positive value .

$\textbf{(1) }$So intuitively , we can think that there exists and infinitesimally small $c \neq 0 $ and this proves the lemma. Is this reasoning correct ?

$\textbf{(2) }$Now , separately i had a look at author's explanation . And this is what i think he is saying . After some initial algebraic manipulation , we arrive to prove that : $$ \exists c \gt 0 \text{ such that } ||\beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{2}+\beta_{3}x_{3}+....+\beta_{n}x_{n}|| \geq c \tag{2}$$  where $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}|\beta_{i}| = 1$$ .
Now to prove $\textit{ equation 2 }$this , what the author is trying to do is that he creates a sequence which contains  all the possible values for 
$$\beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{2}+\beta_{3}x_{3}+....+\beta_{n}x_{n}
\tag {3}  $$  with a norm over it .And then he proves that this sequence converges to a a point , and the value of the point is not  $0$ , and  hence all elements of the of the sequences are not $0$ and hence the same intution , that followed in $\textit{Point (1.) }$follows here .
So is this deduction by me correct ? If that is the case , why did not the author just used $\textit{Point (1.) }$ ?

$\textbf{(3) }$Lastly i want to confirm my understanding of how he created  the sequence :  Let the sequence be denoted by $(y_{m})$ with the general element given by $$y_{m}= \beta_{1}^{(m)}x_{1}+\beta_{2}^{(m)}x_{2}+\beta_{3}^{(m)}x_{3}+....\beta_{n}^{(m)}x_{n}$$ . So that for m =1 ,2 , we have : 
$$y_{1} =\beta_{1}^{(1)}x_{1}+\beta_{2}^{(1)}x_{2}+\beta_{3}^{(1)}x_{3}+....\beta_{n}^{(1)}x_{n}  \\
y_{2} =\beta_{1}^{(2)}x_{1}+\beta_{2}^{(2)}x_{2}+\beta_{3}^{(2)}x_{3}+....\beta_{n}^{(2)}x_{n} \\
.\\
.\\
.\\
y_{m} =\beta_{1}^{(m)}x_{1}+\beta_{2}^{(m)}x_{2}+\beta_{3}^{(m)}x_{3}+....\beta_{n}^{(m)}x_{n} \tag{4}
 $$
Now we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}|\beta_{i}^{m}| =1 $ , this implies that $|\beta_{i}^{m}| \leq 1$ . So we can say that the sequence $$(\beta_{1}^{1},\beta_{1}^{2},\beta_{1}^{3}...)$$is bounded and by the BW theorem , there exists its sub sequence which is convergent and let that point of convergence be called $\beta_{1}$ .The author then writes $\textit{Let } (y_{1,m}) \textit{ be the corresponding sub sequence of } y_{m}$. I want to confirm if the general element of the $(y_{1,m})$ looks like : $$y_{1,m} = \beta_{1}x_{1}+ \beta_{2}^{m}x_{2}+\beta_{3}^{m}x_{3} +.....+ \beta_{n}^{m}x_{n}$$
Is that correct ?

$\textbf{(4) }$ And we repeat the process and reach the $\textit{ expression 3 }$.

Edit 1 : I wrongly ordered the quantifiers as pointed out by @Matthew Towers. It has been fixed now. Also the language around c  has been changed to make "c" look more like a constant.
Edit 2 : Typo around $|.|$ in equation 1 fixed.

Comment: I fixed my mistake regarding ordering of quantifiers and the confusing statement i wrote along the constant c . 
What about my points 1.) ,2.) , 3.) and 4.) . ? Can you explain why they are wrong ?

Comment: Equation (1) still isn't right: it should be $|\alpha_1| + |\alpha_2|+\cdots$ not $|\alpha_1 + \alpha_2+\cdots$.  Point (1): no, that's not what's happening. (2) isn't the right idea.  Kreyszig proceeds by contradiction: if no such $c$ existed then (for example) for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a $y$ in that form with $||y || < \epsilon$, so you can find a sequence of $y_m$ with $||y_m|| \to 0$.